# How can I fork&exec bash shell in C?

Tags: c, linux, bash, shell

Trying to create a new bash shell in C and bring it to the user, this is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    
    char* secretpass = "password";
    char password[50];

    printf("%s", "Password: ");
    fgets(password, 50, stdin);
    password[strcspn(password, "\n")] = 0;

    if (!strcmp(password, secretpass)){
        pid_t pid = fork();
        if (pid == 0){
            execl("/bin/bash", "bash", NULL);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

After running the code (ELF), i get a new bash shell in `ps` but it's not my shell because `echo $$` brings the first shell, what can I do to get the new shell to screen? kernel module will help?

EDIT:

edited my code for more help, /dev/chardev is a char device that come up with the boot process, the driver is also 0666 (.rw.rw.rw.) writable for everyone, the `system(cmd)` says at there is no permission at console, even if I do the command myself after execve.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pwd.h>

#define MAX 50
#define USERNAME 2

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{


    // Declare variables.
    const char* username = argv[USERNAME];
    char* password = (char*)calloc(MAX, sizeof(char));
    char* cmd = (char*)calloc(5 * MAX, sizeof(char));
    char* secretpass = "password";


    printf("%s", "Password: ");
    fgets(password, MAX, stdin);
    password[strcspn(password, "\n")] = 0;

    
    if (!strcmp(password, secretpass)){
        int err;
        
        struct passwd* pw_user = getpwnam(username);
        //printf("-%s-%s-%d-%d-%s-%s-%s-\n", pw_user->pw_name, pw_user->pw_passwd,
         //pw_user->pw_uid, pw_user->pw_gid, pw_user->pw_gecos,
          //pw_user->pw_dir, pw_user->pw_shell);
        

        if ( (err = fchown(0, pw_user->pw_uid, pw_user->pw_gid) ) != 0)
            printf("%s %d\n", "fchown error", err);

        if ( (err = setpgid(0, 0) ) != 0)
            printf("%s %d\n", "setpgid error", err);

        if ( (err = tcsetpgrp(0, getpid()) ) != 0)
            printf("%s %d\n", "tcsetpgrp error", err);

        if ( (err = chdir(pw_user->pw_dir) ) != 0)
            printf("%s %d\n", "chdir error", err);

        if ( (err = setgid(pw_user->pw_gid) ) != 0)
            printf("%s %d\n", "setgid error", err);

        if ( (err = setuid(pw_user->pw_uid) ) != 0)
            printf("%s %d\n", "setuid error", err);



        sprintf(cmd, "%s \"%d %d %d\" %s", "echo", pw_user->pw_uid, pw_user->pw_gid, getpid(), "> /dev/chardev");
        system(cmd);

        const char *args[] = {"bash", "--rcfile", "/etc/bashrc", NULL};

        char LOGNAME[MAX];
        char HOME[MAX];
        char USER[MAX];
        sprintf(LOGNAME, "%s%s", "LOGNAME=", pw_user->pw_name);
        sprintf(HOME, "%s%s", "HOME=",pw_user->pw_dir);
        sprintf(USER, "%s%s", "USER=", pw_user->pw_name);

        const char *env[] = {"SHELL=/bin/bash", LOGNAME, HOME, USER, "IFS= ","PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin", "TTY=tty1", NULL}; /* need to generate these; TTY is passed to you */

        execve("/bin/bash", args, env);

    }
    else
        execl("/bin/login", "login", NULL);


    return 0;
}
```

always setpgid error and if username isn't root there are also setuid and chdir errors.

Comment: Your program doesn't [`wait`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/wait.2.html) for the child process to exit, so it exits leaving the child process as an orphan in the background, while the shell you ran your program continues to run in the foreground.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I think there'll additionally be issues with the stdio streams and TTY stuff, if OP wants an interactive bash.

Comment: Do you want your program to carry on after the new shell exits? If not, you could just exec the new shell from your program without forking.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude the wait helped thanks, now I can't make some of the commands because I don't have permission to, what does that mean?, I am trying to make a new login program instead of /bin/login, execl() isn't enough to make a shell?
even bashrc isn't loaded because of permission error. Can I set a user before execl()?
I can change the creds with linux kernel module but I can't write to the char device even if it's 0666 mode.

Comment: Creating a  login program for Linux is not trivial. First of all, since it has to be run using super-user privileges it can't contain any bugs at all. Secondly it have to change the user to the one being logged in, and do it correctly. It also have to execute the correct shell. And of course use the correct API's to verify the password (PAM etc.). And thirdly, few modern systems use the login program in a way that is visible to standard users., as all they will see is a GUI login prompt (if they don't autologin).

Comment: I understand and still, I want to get an interactive shell, I searched a bit and I found this https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/322201/agetty-login-program-arguments/322204#322204?newreg=ff9a94859a8a4451989e6232d1000d5a
this is my error and I tried --rcfile /etc/bashrc, do you know maybe how to fix that?

Answer (score 2):

From the comments: you're trying to write a login program.

Ok. That's a bit more, and you're going about this all the wrong way. We don't want to fork at all. Let `init` worry about waiting. Anyway, we get to write a long sequence here:

```
    int targetuid = ... ; /* You need a strategy for getting this */
    int targetgid = ... ; /* You need a strategy for getting this */
    const char *homdir = ... ; /* You need a strategy for getting this */
    if (!strcmp(password, secretpass)){
        /* Start up the user's shell */
        fchown(0, targetuid, targetgid);
        setpgid(0, 0);
        tcsetpgrp(0, getpid());
        chdir(homedir);
        setgid(targetgid);
        setuid(targetuid);
        const char *args[] = {"-bash", NULL};
        const char *env[] = {"SHELL=/bin/bash", "LOGNAME=...", "HOME=...", "USER=...", IFS="...", PATH=/bin:/usr/bin", "TERM=...", NULL }; /* need to generate these; TERM is passed to you */
        execve("/bin/bash", args, env);
    }
```

This is very much involved and I actually don't recommend this unless you really have to. I learned a ton when I tried this but it took forever to get it working right.

Particular subpoints: 1) The tty device needs to be owned by the user after a successful login. Thus the `fchown(0, ...)` call to give ownership to the user. 2) The `chdir()` first is traditional; you could reverse the order if you wanted to but I don't see why. 3) Starting the shell with a leading - in argv0 tells the shell that it's a login shell. Check in `ps -f` and you can see this.

I picked up your new code; it actually looks pretty good. The only mistake I can spot is my own; the variable is `TERM` not `TTY` (now corrected in my sample above) and the best place to get its value is `getenv()`. On running your code I only had to make only one correction; that is putting the `-bash` back. The only error it spits out is the one about `chardev`; what is `chardev`?

I guess your failures aren't in this code at all but rather in your kernel.

Info from chat: OP has a custom kernel with a custom `/dev/chardev`; I can't explain the failures as the code works for me. There may or may not be other changes to the kernel.

Comment: Thanks, tried doing everything you did and still, there is no permission to do simple commands, Anything you missed?

Comment: @Ori: Check permissions on the path to the home folder. If you're in a directory you have no permissions to, almost nothing works.

Comment: I am trying to write into my device in /dev folder, the device is 0666 umask and can be written from any user when im not trying the login program, when I get my shell from the login program I can't write into the file. Do you know something about creating the shell for the first time?

Comment: @Ori: The login shell is clearly created with the execve line and giving it -bash as argv0; however you seem to have messed something else up elsewhere.

Comment: Can you check this? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/322201/agetty-login-program-arguments/322204#322204?newreg=ff9a94859a8a4451989e6232d1000d5a
I have seen this also here, how is it possible that I can’t write into a public file? I think that there is problem with the creating or user creds at creating or something like this.

Comment: @Ori: You need to post more details. We don't understand how you got into that strange shape.

Comment: Edit has been done. Actually I checked and some of the commands are not working, setpgid is not working at all, setuid is working only if i use uid 0.

Comment: @Ori: I'll have to have a look at this later. In any case you can simplify part of your code by calling `getpwent()` rather than `popen()` for `awk`.

Comment: yes I’ve seen that after ill change it, waiting for the response.

Comment: @Ori: Updated for new code

Comment: First of all THANKS!!, still not working :( I can tell you that it's working if it's not running from the login screen, it's working if I already logged in and ill get a new shell of the user specified, I do get errors from (setpgid, chdir, setuid) but only if it's from the login screen, I think there is another problem, not sure. All env vars are ok, I do not have permission to get my /home/user/.bashrc, one of the permission problem, can't userstand why.

Comment: Can you also explain what is fchown with fd=0? why are you trying to chdir before setgid and setuid? and why do we use "-bash" and not "bash", can't add arguments if it's "-bash". Thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237722/discussion-between-ori-and-joshua).